# How to query has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails app, I have 3 models: User, Language and Gamification. They are linked via has_many through so:

```
User
has_many :gamifications 
has_many :languages, -> { distinct }, through: :gamifications

Language
has_many :gamifications
has_many :users, -> { distinct }, through: :gamifications

Gamification
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :language
```

Language has got a 'name' column and Gamification has got a 'points' column.

I'm trying to write a method for User model that would return points from the first user's gamification that is linked to the language I query.

Something like that works:

```
def points(language)
  gamifications.where(language_id: language).first
end
```

but I would really like to query language.name rather than language.id. So far I have

```
def points(language)
  gamifications.where(languages: { name: language }).first
end
```

but it triggers
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "language"

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join tables for your query, you need to also chain on a call to `#joins`:

```
def points(language)
  gamifications.joins(:language).where(languages: { name: language }).first
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris! That was very quick and works well, I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem @pawciorr!

Comment: you could use `find_by` instead of `where` if you're just going to call `#first` on the collection